# Update statment in while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a=0;
        while (a++ < 4) {
            System.out.println("Check");
        }
    }
}
```

Here we get result:

```
Check
Check
Check
Check
```

But I have one doubt that is:

> In the while loop there is no update statement to execute to loop repeatedly.

I think that answer is one time *check* only, but when I execute code it shows four times *check*.

I am a not an IT student, so please explain to me clearly so that I can understand.

Comment: `while(condition) { code; }` will execute `code` repeatedly until `condition` is false. `a++` is the same as `a=a+1` and will increment `a`. Your code is the same as `while(a < 4) { a = a + 1; System.out.println("Check"); }` if that helps.

Comment: short: `a++` is incrementing the value of `a` and returning the previous value of `a` - the condition  (expression) and the while block are repeat *while* the condition results in `true`. Once the condition evaluates to `false`, the block is not executed and the whole while statement is terminated

Answer (score -1):

The condition `a++ < 4` is indeed evaluated, but it's also executed. Let's break it down:

The condition `a++ < 4` consists of three parts:

`a++`: This is a post-increment operator. It increments the value of a by 1 after the current value of a is evaluated in the expression.
< 4: This is a comparison operator that checks if the value of a (before it's incremented) is less than 4.
During the evaluation of the condition, a is compared with 4. If a is less than 4, the condition evaluates to true, and the code inside the loop is executed. If a is not less than 4, the loop terminates.

After the condition is **evaluated**, a is incremented by 1 due to **the a++ part of the condition**. This happens regardless of whether the condition evaluated to true or false.

The condition is both **evaluated** and **executed**. The evaluation determines whether the loop should continue or terminate, while the execution updates the value of a for the next iteration.

Comment: detail: `a` is NOT incremented after the condition - not relevant in posted code, but it would be relevant if, for example, `a` is **also** used on the right side of the `<`. From [JLS 15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) and subsequent: "The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated." and "... guarantees that every operand of an operator (...) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed."